# VBA - Insert Formula referencing other sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with two sheets. In sheet A few cells have to change if data in few cells of Sheet B changes.

For example Sheet B Cell A1 is changed then same has to be reflected for Sheet A Cell A1.

I was thinking of just inserting a formula like `=Sheet B!A1` in A1 of Sheet A. Can you guys help me solve this problem? Any other approaches are more than welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any issue you are facing using `=Sheet B!A1` in `Cell A1` of `Sheet A`?

Comment: Hi, Im unable to insert the formula using VBA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like below should help

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim srcSht As Worksheet, destSht As Worksheet
    Set srcSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet B")
    Set destSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet A")
    destSht.Range("A1") = srcSht.Range("A1")
End Sub
```

This will copy value of `Sheet B!A1` in `Sheet A!A1`. If you want formula then change

```
destSht.Range("A1") = srcSht.Range("A1")
```

to

```
destSht.Range("A1").Formula = "=Sheet B!A1"
```

***EDIT :***

Use

```
destSht.Range("A1").Formula = "=" & srcSht.Name & "!A1"  'if you are using Worksheet variable
```

or

```
destSht.Range("A1").Formula = "=" & str & "!A1" 'if you are using String variable
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. But in my case I have the sheet name in a variable as there are multiple sheets. Can you suggest any alternative approach?

Comment: @Mrig Just to mention that if there is a space in the name of the sheet like this  `"=Sheet B!A1"` it won't work. We need to enclose the name in `'` then like `='Sheet B'!A1` therefore when using variables I suggest **always** to enclose them in `'` because we never know what the variable value is: `"='" & srcSht.Name & "'!A1"` (same for `str` of course).

Comment: Thanks, How to apply this for multiple columns range.